# Unable to deploy new jhipster application to Cloud Foundry

Tags: jhipster

I'm trying to deploy a new jhipster application to cloud foundry keep getting the error below. I didn't have any problems before. any ideas on what can be wrong?

```
Uploading segundo...

REQUEST: [2015-11-07T11:25:18-05:00]
PUT /v2/resource_match HTTP/1.1
Host: api.run.pivotal.io
Accept: application/json
Authorization: [PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN]
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: go-cli 6.13.0-e68ce0f / linux

null

RESPONSE: [2015-11-07T11:25:18-05:00]
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Length: 99
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Date: Sat, 07 Nov 2015 16:27:21 GMT
Server: nginx
X-Cf-Requestid: 3d72ac61-69ac-414e-7d59-b7238a0adce0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Vcap-Request-Id: f700dd35-a26b-4790-7c29-8d60b95a8eb0::3092ce9d-2adf-4d18-a566-6506185e659f

{
  "error_code": "UnknownError",
  "description": "An unknown error occurred.",
  "code": 10001
}

FAILED
Error uploading application.
Server error, status code: 500, error code: 10001, message: An unknown error occurred.
FAILED
Error uploading application.
Server error, status code: 500, error code: 10001, message: An unknown error occurred.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirm this is currently an open issue at https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/2225

Answer (score 0):

It could be a number of things. `cf logs segundo --recent` is your friend here.

Potentially, the problem is simply that CloudFoundry is having some sort of internal instability and trying again later will rectify the problem. I've had similar issues before that were resolved by waiting a bit.